# how to save data in multiple tables with the one form

Tags: laravel

I have 2 tables: `customers` and `address` one form to save data into this tables. For this, I made the relation like:

> Address model

```
public function customer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class);
}
```

> customer model

```
public function address()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Address::class);
}
```

How can i save the address in table? I already done with `customer` i can save, update and delete. I read the DOC of Eloquent of laravel, but i don't really get it.

> Here is my controller

```
class CustomerController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        //        $customer = Customer::all();
        $customer = Customer::with('address')->get();;

        return view('customer.index', compact('customer'));

    }

    public function create(Address $address)
    {
        $address = $address->all();
        return view('customer.create');
    }


    public function store(CustomerRequest $request , Customer $customer)
    {
        $customer = Customer::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('customer.index',compact('customer'));
    }


    public function show(Customer $customer)
    {
        return view('customer.show',compact('customer'));
    }


    public function edit(Customer $customer)
    {
        return view('customer.edit', compact('customer'));
    }


    public function update(CustomerRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $customer = Customer::find($id)->update($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('customer.index',compact('customer'));
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        Customer::destroy($id);
        return redirect()->route('customer.index');
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated!!

Comment: You have to update in parallel with customer table.

Comment: what error you have?

Comment: You can do it like this `$customer->address()->save($address);` in the `store` mrthod !!

Comment: i add that to my controller      public function store(CustomerRequest $request , Customer $customer, Address $address)
    {
        $customer = Customer::create($request->all());
        $address = Address::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('customer.index',compact('customer','address'));
    }     but now i get this error customer_id does not have a default value

Comment: Try it like this `public function store(CustomerRequest $request) { 
 $customer = Customer::create($request->all()); 
 $address = Address::create($request->all()); 
 $customer->address()->save($address);
 return redirect()->route('customer.index',compact('customer','addre‌​ss')); }` remove useless parameters !

Comment: Thanks for you replay. I still get the same error. customer_id does not have a default value

Comment: Try it like this : `public function store(CustomerRequest $request) { 
 $customer = Customer::create($request->all()); 
 $address = new Address($request->all()); 
 $customer->address()->save($address);
 return redirect()->route('customer.index',compact('customer','addre‌​ss')); }` !

Comment: i solved like that.   $customerData = $request->only('firstName',
            'lastName',
            'email',
            'phone');

        $customer = Customer::create($customerData);

        $addressData = $request->only(   'country',
            'postcode',
            'homeNumber',
            'streetName',
            'addition',
            'city',
            'province');

        $address = new Address($addressData);
        $address->customer()->associate($customer);

        $address->save();

Comment: what about my last comment ? just to see if this will work as well :)

Comment: unfortunately it gives me error